# how to increase fps for raspberry pi for object detection

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi, object-detection, yolo

I'm having low fps for real-time object detection on my raspberry pi

I trained the yolo-darkflow object detection on my own data set using my laptop windows 10 .. when I tested the model for real-time detection on my laptop with webcam it worked fine with high fps

However when trying to test it on my raspberry pi, which runs on Raspbian OS, it gives very low fps rate that is about 0.3 , but when I only try to use the webcam without the yolo it works fine with fast frames.. also when I use Tensorflow API for object detection with webcam on pi it also works fine with high fps

can someone suggest me something please? is the reason related to the yolo models or opencv or phthon? how can I make the fps rate higher and faster for object detection with webcam?

Comment: 1) Instead of using the `cv2.VideoCapture()`, try using `imutils.WebcamVideoStream` which is the same as the former but implements threading.
2) Use a mini version of the model optimised for edge devices like the raspberry pi

Answer (score 0):

The raspberry pi not have the GPU procesors and because of that is very hard for it to do image recognition at a high fps .

Answer (score 0):

My detector on raspberry pi without any accelerator can reach 5 FPS.
I used SSD mobilenet, and quantize it after training.
Tensorflow Lite supplies a object detection demo can reach about 8 FPS on raspberry pi 4.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Coral AI accelerator with raspberry pi. It is an USB accelerator from which you can get upto 14fps. Check this https://coral.ai/docs/accelerator/get-started/#requirements

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).